# chose path fopen with variable file name in C

Tags: c, variables, path, fopen

Let's say I have a variable "NomFichier" that receive the name of my .bin file.

For now i have :

```
FILE fichier = fopen(NomFichier, "wb");
```

So I create my .bin in "Projet AP3\Projet\Code" with my code files.

What could I write to create my file in this path : "Projet AP3\Fichiers .txt et .bin" ? (I would like to write a relative path not an absolute path).

Comment: Relative paths are interpreted relative to the user's directory, not the directory containing the program. Finding the directory of the program depends on the operating system.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you use:

```
char const* NomFichier = "myfile.txt";
```

to create the file in the directory "Projet AP3\Projet\Code", then you can use:

```
char const* NomFichier = "..\\..\\Fichiers\myfile.txt";
```

to create the file in the directory "Project AP3\Fichiers".